# Qual a finalidade do método OnModelCreating e como ele funciona?

Tags: entity-framework-6

Estou estudando Fluent API e estou com essa dúvida, vi que este método pode ser vazio, sem nenhuma implementação. Então qual a utilidade dele e como funciona o método OnModelCreating que fica na classe de contexto que pertence a classe DbContex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Segundo a documentação da MSDN a respeito](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

> This method is called when the model for a derived context has been initialized, but before the model has been locked down and used to initialize the context. The default implementation of this method does nothing, but it can be overridden in a derived class such that the model can be further configured before it is locked down.

Traduzindo:

> Este método é chamado quando o modelo para um contexto derivado foi inicializado, mas antes que o modelo foi bloqueado e usado para inicializar o contexto. A implementação padrão deste método não faz nada, mas pode ser substituído em uma classe derivada de tal forma que o modelo pode ser ainda configurado antes de ser bloqueado.

Ele serve para definir associações extras entre modelos, chaves primárias, estrangeiras, realizar algumas ações de verificação sobre o contexto, etc.

As associações são definidas [através da *Fluent API*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx).

Opinativamente falando, trabalhar com o `OnModelCreating` é menos interessante que definir as associações dentro de cada *Model* através de atributos. Isto porque, conforme o sistema cresce, a complexidade de configuração da base por este método do contexto vai aumentando, e a manutenção fica mais difícil.

[Temos várias respostas a respeito da *Fluent API* aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluent+api). Acho que vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: Então pelo que eu entendi nas suas explicações, o Fluent API só pode ser definido neste método diferente dos Data Annotations correto?

Comment: @KellySoares Isso mesmo.